# how to combine more than two file into one new file with specific name using bash

Tags: bash, pattern-matching, match, multiple-columns, cat

I have many file
list file name:

- p004c01.txt
- p004c05.txt
- p006c01.txt
- p006c02.txt
- p007c01.txt
- p007c03.txt
- p007c04.txt
  ...

> $cat p004c01.txt
> #header
> 122.5 -0.256 547
> 123.6  NaN   325

> $cat p004c05.txt
> #header
> 122.1  2.054  247
> 122.2 -1.112  105

> $cat p006c01.txt
> #header
> 99    -0.200 333
> 121.4 -1.206 243

> $cat p006c02.txt
> #header
> 122.5  2.200 987
> 99    -1.335 556

I want the file be like this
file1

> $cat p004.txt
> 122 -0.256 547
> 122  2.054 247
> 122 -1.112 105

file2

> $cat p006.txt
> 122.5  2.200 987
> 121.4 -1.206 243
> 99    -1.335 556
> 99    -0.200 333

And the other file too
File that contain the same value (?) in

> p????cxx.txt

is in the same new file
I tried one by one file like this

> cat p004* | sed '/#/d'| sort -k 1n | sed '/NaN/d' |awk '{print substr($1,2,3),$2,$3,$4,$5}' > p004.txt

Anyone can help me with the simple script for all the data?
Thank you :)

Comment: @jared_mamrot `i've tried but it dosent work :( for f in {001..999};do cat < (tail -n +2 p"$f"c*) > p"$f".txt;done
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('  `
i don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will work for you:

```
for f in {001..999}; do tail -n +2 p"$f"c* > p"$f".txt; done 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: You can also add `-q` to the `tail` command to remove having the file's names appear on the output.

Comment: Yes, definitely it work on me. Thank you @jared_mamrot

Comment: Thankss @guzmonne